# Cancel all timer when starting another activity

Tags: android, optimization

I have  an activity A which as multiple timers.

What I want to do is that cancel all the timers when I move from A to B so that the timer started in A doesnt affect activity B.
I tried to cancel it on pause but it doesnt seems to work.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

i have a List that when start a timer , add this in List

```
 List<Timer> timers;
```

....

```
timers.add(myTimer);
```

and in `onPause` cancel all:

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    for (int i =0;i<timers.size();i++){
        timers.get(i).cancel();
    }
}
```